# Add CRL Distribution Points (CDP) Extension to X509Certificate2 Certificate

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509certificate2, .net-4.7.2

I trying to add certificate extension to my X509Certificate2 object **in pure .NET 4.7.2**

I was using BouncyCastle by this method:

```
private static void AddCdpUrl(X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator, string cdptUrl)
{
    var uriGeneralName = new GeneralName(GeneralName.UniformResourceIdentifier, cdptUrl);
    var cdpName = new DistributionPointName(DistributionPointName.FullName, uriGeneralName);
    var cdp = new DistributionPoint(cdpName, null, null);
    certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.CrlDistributionPoints, false, new CrlDistPoint(new[] { cdp }));
}
```

Add its works and I get great result:
[image]

Now in pure .NET I am using this method:

```
const string X509CRLDistributionPoints = "2.5.29.31";    
certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509Extension(new Oid(X509CRLDistributionPoints), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("http://crl.example.com"), false));
```

And get this result:
[image]

I am missing the sequences for "Distribution Point Name", "Full Name" and "URL="

How can I generate the same result that BouncyCastle does with pure .NET
Thanks

Comment: .NET doesn't support CDP extension. You have to use 3rd party libraries for that. BC is ok if it works for you.

Comment: @Crypt32- I don't want to use BC

Comment: Then find something else. Inventing your own code is cost-ineffective. At least without a decent ASN.1 library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (2023-03-20):** .NET 7 now has the [CertificateRevocationListBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterevocationlistbuilder.buildcrldistributionpointextension?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-certificaterevocationlistbuilder-buildcrldistributionpointextension(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-boolean)) method to do this for you (and isn't even limited to a single 119-character value!).

```
X509Extension cdpExtension =
    CertificateRevocationListBuilder.BuildCrlDistributionPointExtension(
        new[] { url });
```

##### Original Answer (.NET <7)

If you only want to write one distribution point, and it's less than or equal to 119 ASCII characters long, and you aren't delegating CRL signing authority to a different certificate:

```
private static X509Extension MakeCdp(string url)
{
    byte[] encodedUrl = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);

    if (encodedUrl.Length > 119)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    byte[] payload = new byte[encodedUrl.Length + 10];
    int offset = 0;
    payload[offset++] = 0x30;
    payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.Length + 8);
    payload[offset++] = 0x30;
    payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.Length + 6);
    payload[offset++] = 0xA0;
    payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.Length + 4);
    payload[offset++] = 0xA0;
    payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.Length + 2);
    payload[offset++] = 0x86;
    payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(encodedUrl, 0, payload, offset, encodedUrl.Length);

    return new X509Extension("2.5.29.31", payload, critical: false);
}
```

Past 119 characters the outer payload length exceeds `0x7F` and then you really start wanting a proper DER encoder. You definitely want one for variable numbers of URLs, or including any of the optional data from the extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late, but you could use BC as a utility to get the DER-encoded extension and import it into native .NET like so:

```
// req is a .NET Core 3.1 CertificateRequest object
req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
    new X509Extension(
          new Oid("2.5.29.31"),
          crlDistPoint.GetDerEncoded(), // this is your CRL extension
          false
          )
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and now there is a AsnWriter available (thanks @bartonjs, looks like you got the namespace you wanted :)), if you're on at least NET5.
So I've cobbled together a method which creates the extension using the writer:

```
/// <summary>Derived from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/src/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/Asn1/DistributionPointAsn.xml.cs</summary>
private static X509Extension BuildDistributionPointExtension(string[] fullNames, ReasonFlagsAsn? reasons, string[]? crlIssuers, bool critical) {
    var writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    writer.PushSequence();
    writer.PushSequence(Asn1Tag.Sequence);

    writer.PushSequence(new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 0));
    writer.PushSequence(new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 0));
    //See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Common/src/System/Security/Cryptography/Asn1/GeneralNameAsn.xml.cs for different value types
    for(int i = 0; i < fullNames.Length; i++) writer.WriteCharacterString(UniversalTagNumber.IA5String, fullNames[i], new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 6)); //GeneralName 6=URI
    writer.PopSequence(new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 0));
    writer.PopSequence(new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 0));

    if(reasons.HasValue) writer.WriteNamedBitList(reasons.Value, new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 1));
    if(crlIssuers?.Length > 0) {
        writer.PushSequence(new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 2));
        for(int i = 0; i < crlIssuers.Length; i++) writer.WriteCharacterString(UniversalTagNumber.IA5String, crlIssuers[i], new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 2)); //GeneralName 2=DnsName
        writer.PopSequence(new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 2));
    }
 
    writer.PopSequence(Asn1Tag.Sequence);
    writer.PopSequence();

    return new X509Extension(new Oid("2.5.29.31"), writer.Encode(), critical);
}
[Flags] internal enum ReasonFlagsAsn { Unused = 1 << 0, KeyCompromise = 1 << 1, CACompromise = 1 << 2, AffiliationChanged = 1 << 3, Superseded = 1 << 4, CessationOfOperation = 1 << 5, CertificateHold = 1 << 6, PrivilegeWithdrawn = 1 << 7, AACompromise = 1 << 8 }
```

Just be careful and do your own tests as I've only checked if the CRL is properly displayed in a cert viewer.